# "Stringing" conduit together

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

Is it OK to take a piece of string and slip the conduit pieces you are putting together onto it before you assemble them? I was thinking that doing this would be easier than trying to fish or feed a guide-string through the conduit, or simply pulling the wires through it without a guide-string to help with the process...

Comment: The electricians on the job have done it quite often. Make sure you conduit is sized properly for the amount of wire that will be passing through it.

Comment: @Jack, "real" electrician will not do this very often. A MUCH more professional, and easier, way is to simply push a snake in after the run is complete, or to use a vacuum and suck in a jet line with a baloon or foam plug on the end.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey come to think of it, the vacuum idea is a darn good one.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, for anything over like 150' that's all I do. Jet line is only like $65 for something like 5000'. I then use the jet line to pull in a Mule-Tape. You CANNOT use the jet line to pull wire, it'll cut into the conduit real quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assemble it first, before wires, but putting the string in as you put it together is fine.

300.18 Raceway Installations

(A) Complete Runs. Raceways, other than busways or exposed raceways having hinged or removable covers, shall be installed complete between outlet, junction, or splicing points prior to the installation of conductors.